# Python: Best way to define and re-use an object for subsequent tests using `pytest`

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, pytest

I have some tests running on my Python package using `pytest`. However, I am noticing that I am re-writing a lot of times an object that is necessary for the function I am testing.

For the sake of the example, consider the following function `foo()`.

```
def foo(dictionary:dict, key:str):
    """
    Get the value of a key from a dictionary

    ----------
    Parameters:
        dictionary: dictionary
        key: the key to get the value from
    ----------
    Returns:
        value of the key

    """
    return dictionary[key]
```

Now, I have another Python script where I have written the following three tests for the `foo()` function.

```
from mypackage.module_where_foo_is_located import foo

def test_foo_one():
    dict_used_by_many_tests = {'name': 'Dionysia', 'age': 28, 'location': 'Athens'}
    actual = foo(dict_used_by_many_tests, "name")
    expected = "Dionysia"
    assert actual == expected

def test_foo_two():
    dict_used_by_many_tests = {'name': 'Dionysia', 'age': 28, 'location': 'Athens'}
    actual = foo(dict_used_by_many_tests, "age")
    expected =   28
    assert actual == expected


def test_foo_three():
    dict_used_by_many_tests = {'name': 'Dionysia', 'age': 28, 'location': 'Athens'}
    actual = foo(dict_used_by_many_tests, "location")
    expected = "Athens"
    assert actual == expected
```

Here is my question: what strikes me immediately as *"bad form"* is the fact that I have the dictionary `dict_used_by_many_tests` repeated three times... so, **what's the best way to define and re-use it for the three tests?**

I think one way to do it is simply to define `dict_used_by_many_tests = {'name': 'Dionysia', 'age': 28, 'location': 'Athens'}` once before defining the tests functions, but, it seems very unsafe in situations in which tests might change the content of `dict_used_by_many_tests` as part of the testing, so subsequent tests will not start with a fresh copy of this shared object. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are asking for [`pytest.fixture`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html). It lets you define an object and pass it as a parameter to your test functions.

To use it in your particular case just write a function that returns your dictionary.

```
@pytest.fixture
def dict_used_by_many_tests():
    return {'name': 'Dionysia', 'age': 28, 'location': 'Athens'}


def test_foo_one(dict_used_by_many_tests):
    actual = foo(dict_used_by_many_tests, "name")
    expected = "Dionysia"
    assert actual == expected
```

Fixture written as it is will return a different dictionary for each test case. This means, you can modify your dictionary in your test without worrying for side effects in other tests.

If you have lots of tests that use the same dictionary and don't want to modify them all to make them receive the dictionary you can use the flag `autouse`:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def dict_used_by_many_tests():
    return {'name': 'Dionysia', 'age': 28, 'location': 'Athens'}


def test_foo_one():
    # Can use the fixture even though it is not an argument
    actual = foo(dict_used_by_many_tests, "name")
    expected = "Dionysia"
    assert actual == expected
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a module-scoped fixture, so that the `dict` is defined once for the module and passed to each test function.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def data():
    return {'name': 'Dionysia', 'age': 28, 'location': 'Athens'}


def test_foo_one(data):
     actual = foo(data, "name")
     expected = "Dionysia"
     assert actual == expected


def test_foo_two(data):
    actual = foo(data, "age")
    expected = 28
    assert actual == expected


def test_foo_three(data):
    actual = foo(data, "location")
    expected = "Athens"
    assert actual == expected
```

The test runner would then do something equivalent to

```
# Same dict object passed to each test
value = data()
test_foo_one(value)
test_foo_two(value)
test_foo_three(value)
```

Just take care that you don't *modify* `data` in each test, as changes would be visible to any tests that follow. (Or, you can drop the scoping:

```
@pytext.fixture
def data():
    return ...
```

to ensure a fresh `dict` is created for each test, which would result in the runner executing something like

```
test_foo_one(data())
test_foo_two(data())
test_foo_three(data())
```

)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @chepner. Could you elaborate on what do you mean by *"Or, you can drop the scoping to ensure a fresh dict is created for each test"*? How would I do this in the code you provided?

Comment: Just drop the `scope="module"` argument. By default, `test_foo_one` would be executed with something like `test_foo_one(data())`, with `data` being called on demand. With `scope="module"`, you get something like a global `data_value = data()`, and the test is executed with `test_foo_one(data_value)`.

Comment: See https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session for more on scoping of fixtures.

Comment: I see, thank you. Additionally, I think there is a typo in your answer. I think you typed `pytext` instead of `pytest` on the decorator at the top.

Comment: Yeah, I frequently type `test` for `text` and vice versa in many contexts. (Had to double-check this comment to make sure I hadn't typed "contests" by accident.)